# Just_Audio cant next if i'm using shuffle

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I have problem with just_audio flutter when i click shuffle button i cant back/skip the music

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSVHM.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I using code sample in just_audio src for trial

Comment: If the unmodified official example has a bug, can you file a bug report instead?